# post maven artifact to file upload servlet

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

We have a servlet that we post a zip file to. I would like to automate building the zip and posting it to the servlet with maven. Is there a way to do that with maven plugins or should I just use external tools or ant tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up using some ant/curl:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <exec executable="curl">
                            <arg value="-F"/>
                            <arg value="file=@target/templates.zip"/>
                            <arg value="http://localhost:8080/template/process"/>
                        </exec>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) should help with this use case.

Answer (score 0):

The [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) can transfer your built zip artifact to the servlet.  The [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal has parameters where you can explicitly set the URL to upload to.  Or you can set up the [distribution management section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) in the POM to do it the standard way.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough customization of the POST using this method. We can't alter the servlet so I had to go with an ant task.